# gson.fromJson bug? Can not parse valid json

Tags: java, json

Method

```
private boolean isJSONValid(String test) {
    try {
        gson.fromJson(test, Object.class);
        return true;
    } catch (com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

returns false on this JSON - `{"R":"CsIGAADwPxIESS5PSw==","I":"70"}`
I believe this is normal JSON, prove me if it doesn't, and tell please why

Comment: Never, never, never hide exceptions in `catch` block. You should atleast print in log what is that exception.

Comment: Why you tap "-" ? Yhat is WebsocketTransport code, I just use it

Comment: If you can log the exception in the catch block we can aware of the issue

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and it's working properly:

```
public static void main( String[] args ){
    System.out.println( isJSONValid( "{'R':'CsIGAADwPxIESS5PSw==','I':'70'}" ) );
}

private static boolean isJSONValid( String test ){
    try{
        new Gson().fromJson( test, Object.class );
        return true;
    }
    catch( com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException ex ){
        return false;
    }
}
```

This prints `true`. Your issue can be the unseen unicode charachters on your incoming `String`. Please log your exception every time! to clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

it is working fine... when escaping double quotes....

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
```

public class Testing {

```
private boolean isJSONValid(String test) {
    try {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        gson.fromJson(test, Object.class);
        return true;
    } catch (com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
        return false;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Testing isj = new Testing();
    String test = "{\"R\":\"CsIGAADwPxIESS5PSw==\",\"I\":\"70\"}";
    System.out.println(isj.isJSONValid(test));
}
```

}